# Burninate this [catastrophic-failure] of a tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [catastrophic-failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catastrophic-failure) appears to be used for segfaults and other fatal errors, which is a fairly wide range of things.  Most of the 29 questions are asked by new users, and there is only 1 follower.  It should probably be removed.

The specific issues with it are that it is broad (many things can be catastrophic failures in many different contexts) and doesn't add any information that couldn't be found in the question.  Plus, nobody can be an expert in [catastrophic-failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catastrophic-failure)s.

Comment: I can think of a few movie characters that might fit the "expert" bill, but yeah, this tag should *burn* errr.. have a catastrophic error.

Comment: I've been known to complain about bad puns in tag burnination requests, but this one gets a +1 just for the title (the issue merits a +1 too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag has been edited out. Will be removed from the system within 24h.